# How to use a REST API to convert any amount from one currency to another

Tags: api, rest, currency

I am looking for an API that can use to convert any amount from one currency to another. I am specifically looking to convert from SouthAfrican rands to Nigerian naira.

so far I have tried

```
http://data.fixer.io/api/convert

    ? access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
    & from = ZAR
    & to = NGN
    & amount = 25
```

I have also tried

```
http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key = 01ac7912e45de0fb9ab2d3619f85bd54& from = ZAR& to = NGN& amount = 10
```

I have also tried

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=ZAR&to_currency=NGN&apikey=ZRH58691ZX2ENX1U&datatype=json";
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

I found a website that provide an API that matches your needs, you can order a free API key (i'll provide my free key in the following example (**9f13aadc1c18fd085b98**)) :

```
https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=NGN_ZAR&compact=ultra&apiKey=9f13aadc1c18fd085b98
```

With this, i get the following output :

```
{"NGN_ZAR":0.044899}
```

The parameters are pretty simple, you just have to use `q=FROM_TO` where FROM could be `NGN` and TO could be `ZAR`, and the result gives how much *FROM* you need to have 1 *TO* (or the opposite, i didn't do the maths).

You can see the documentation here : https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/docs

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

**apilayer.net**

When i try to GET your apilayer.net request, i get this :

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 101,
    "type": "missing_access_key",
    "info": "You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]"
  }
}
```

It means that you need to provide an API key (you must subscribe to apilayer.net and get an API key) and you should call this URL instead :

```
https://api.currencylayer.com/convert?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY&from=NGN&to=ZAR&amount=10
```

**alphavantage.co**

When i try to GET your alphavantage.co request, i get this :

```
> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=ZAR&to_currency=NGN&apikey=ZRH58691ZX2ENX1U
{
    "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE."
}
```

But when i try with EUR and BTC, i get this :

```
> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=BTC&to_currency=EUR&apikey=ZRH58691ZX2ENX1U
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "BTC",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "9901.50756600",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2020-08-06 09:35:01",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "9901.50756600",
        "9. Ask Price": "9901.51600000"
    }
}
```

The reason is that ZAR and NGN are not recognized as currency symbols by those APIs, even if you provide correct ISO codes for those currencies

Comment: Thanks for the input right now I am still in need of an API that recognises ZAR and NGN. Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: @Zidane i updated my answer with a new API i found, perhaps it will fill your needs.
If it's good for you, could you accept my answer so i can get my reputation points ? (i need 6 more to comment posts)